# Excel VBA - searching PDF using FindText three times per doc

Tags: vba, excel, search

It takes a very long time for some files to be searched. I need to do this with 1000+ PDFs. It seems to be held up during the FindText operation. Any suggestions?

```
Sub pdfSearch()

Dim acroApp As Object, acroDoc As Object
Dim searchString1 As String, searchString2 As String, searchString3 As String
Dim filePath As Variant
Dim i As Long

Sheet3.Range("A4:C999999").ClearContents
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
i = 4
searchString1 = Sheet3.Range("b1").Value
searchString2 = Sheet3.Range("c1").Value
searchString3 = Sheet3.Range("d1").Value
For Each filePath In Sheet2.Range("a1:a25")
    Debug.Print (filePath.Row)
    Set acroApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
    Set acroDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")
    If acroDoc.Open(filePath.Value, "") = -1 Then
        If acroDoc.FindText(searchString1, 0, 0, 1) = -1 Then
            Sheet3.Cells(i, 2).Value = searchString1
            Sheet3.Cells(i, 3).Value = filePath.Value
            i = i + 1
        End If
        If acroDoc.FindText(searchString2, 0, 0, 1) = -1 Then
            Sheet3.Cells(i, 2).Value = searchString2
            Sheet3.Cells(i, 3).Value = filePath.Value
            i = i + 1
        End If
        If acroDoc.FindText(searchString3, 0, 0, 1) = -1 Then
            Sheet3.Cells(i, 2).Value = searchString3
            Sheet3.Cells(i, 3).Value = filePath.Value
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Else:
        MsgBox "PDF not found"
    End If
    acroDoc.Close 0
    Set acroDoc = Nothing
    Set acroApp = Nothing
Next filePath

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Comment: Move your two `CreateObject` lines outside of your loop. There is no need to recreate the object each time.